# Deployment of an angular application on cpanel

Tags: angular

when I run the URL browser throws these error

cpanel path : public_html/asiatride_design/dist

base url on index.html : "/asiatride_design/"

[image]

Comment: If you run the index.html after the build, does it give you the same error? Also, what is the baseHref you provided?

Comment: <base href="/asiatride_design/">

Comment: Ok, but if you open the dist folder -> double click index.html file does the browser give you the same error?

Comment: yes... browser throws the same error ..

Comment: Try changing the baseHref to './', in the DIST index.html file and re-open the same file.

Comment: @SINCYKY,  What is the server type  Apache or nginx?

Comment: Please post `index.html` page.

Comment: server type is Apache.

Comment: is there any configuration in angular.json??

Comment: @ Jacopo Sciampi , './ ' is not work for me